# How to use ICE BLUE mic for FaceTime on iPad Air

Tags: ipad, microphone

I've connected my ICE BLUE to my iPad Air 4th gen via a USB C to USB adapter (Syntech) and my ICE BLUE red light is on but when I test via a FaceTime call, the sound level on the receiving end of the call is no louder with or without the ICE BLUE.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  What have you done to resolve this?  Have you contacted Ice Blue or gone to their site for instructions and support?

Comment: After the microphone arrived, I looked at the on-line documentation more closely and found they're macOS compatible but don't say anything about iOS. I'll contact them to see if there's anything in the works or their toolbox with regards to iOS.

Comment: The response from BLUE was that the mic is not iOS compatible and there are no plans to make it so at this time

Comment: Sorry to hear that.  Can you please add that info as an answer and then accept it?  That way, if anyone else has the same issue or question, they'll find your answer and it could help them.